# Line fetching using awk command

Tags: awk

The below command is used to fetch the Nth line "AFTER" a pattern match, when `n` is a positive number.

But the same command does not work to fetch the Nth line "BEFORE" a pattern match, when I give `n` as a negative number. Could you help with this?

```
awk /pattern_to_match/{x = NR + n}NR == x file_to_search
```

Thanks,
BSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help

```
tac file_to_search | awk '/pattern_to_match/{x = NR + n}NR == x'
```

or

```
awk '{arr[FNR]=$0} /pattern_to_match/{x=FNR-3;if(x in arr){ print arr[x]; exit}}'
```

Examples:

```
$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ seq 10 | tac | awk '/^7/{x = NR + 3}NR == x'
4

$ seq 10 | awk '{arr[FNR]=$0} /^7/{x=FNR-3;if(x in arr){ print arr[x]; exit}}'
4
```

Comment: In the below command ===> awk '{arr[FNR]=$0} /^7/{x=FNR-3;if(x in arr){ print arr[x]; exit}}' ===> where do I provide the filename?

Comment: @BSD `awk '{arr[FNR]=$0} /^7/{x=FNR-3;if(x in arr){ print arr[x]; exit}}' your_file`

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -B N 'pattern_to_match' file_to_search | head -1
```

Replace `N` with the number Nth line before the match that you want.

Example:
File "a" contains:

```
hello
there
how
are
you?
```

Running `grep -B 2 "are" a | head -1` returns `there`.

Possible issue: If there are not `N` rows prior to the match, the 1st row of the file will be returned.